# How to post on my facebook page from my website using Facebook App keys created from my facebook account?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Below is the code i am using to achieve this functionality, and i have successfully posted it to my facebook wall from my website but i am not able to post to my facebook page?

**How can i get page access token using FaceBookClient() in c# SDK?**

```
var client = new FacebookClient();

                    dynamic token = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                    {
                        client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAPI"].ToString(),
                        client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAPIKey"].ToString(),
                        grant_type = "client_credentials"
                    });
                    client.AccessToken = token.access_token;

                    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                    parameters.title = detail.Title;
                    parameters.message = GetDescription(detail.Description, detail.Content);
                    parameters.link = "http://test.com/blog" + detail.RelativeLink;//HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? "http://test.com/blog" + detail.RelativeLink : HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + "" + detail.RelativeLink;

                    var result = client.Post(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageID"].ToString() + "/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

It's clear that you can't use an App Access Token for posting to a Page, because a Post always needs to be related to a profile.

> - A **user access token** with **publish_actions** permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that person. Posts will appear in the voice of the user.
> - A **page access token** with **publish_pages** permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

Comment: How can i get page access token using FaceBookClient() in c# SDK?